# Should I logon to Windows when using xbootmgr to speed up boot times?

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, performance

The below is an (adapted) quotation from [Raymond.cc](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/analyze-windows-7-performance-with-microsoft-windows-performance-toolkit/):

> The Windows Performance Toolkit also has a command to analyze the
>   Windows boot process and make changes so the computer boots as fast as
>   possible. (...) The command is:
>
> ```
> xbootmgr.exe -trace boot -prepSystem -verboseReadyBoot
> ```
>
> The computer will restart six times during the process after which
>   your boot times should be noticeably faster.

Assuming my Windows account is password-protected, should I log in on every reboot, or just leave the computer alone until it's done?

The computer is running Windows 10, but I guess this is not relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you must logon to Windows. Configure your Windows to automatically logon to your system with [Autologon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/autologon.aspx)

[image]

Enter your password and click on `Enable`. After the optimization is done, run autologon again and click on `disable`.

Comment: Thanks. As reference for everyone, the Sysinternals tool is simply a wrapper for the built-in Auto Logon feature of Windows itself, described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872306.aspx).