# Can I run xbootmgr to speed up boot times on an SSD?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, ssd, performance

It is possible to tune up the Windows boot time by using the `xbootmgr` tool from the Windows Performance Toolkit, as described in this related question of myself: [Should I logon to Windows when using xbootmgr to speed up boot times?](https://superuser.com/questions/1070722/should-i-logon-to-windows-when-using-xbootmgr-to-speed-up-boot-times). The command to use is the following:

```
xbootmgr.exe -trace boot -prepSystem -verboseReadyBoot
```

However, the author of the article I'm referring to advises:

> This process should NOT be performed with an SSD boot drive as it will
>   make no difference due to PreFetch, SuperFetch and defragging having
>   virtually no effect on an SSD.

Now, I'm a little confused whether that's a warning or simply an advice to keep people from wasting time. Supposing I do perform this command on an SSD based computer, would it be detrimental (cause damage to the drive, make the boot time longer, or any other negative impact)?

**Update:** I did run the process on my home computer, which has an SSD as the main drive. It finished much faster than normally would. At the end, the boot time improved **absolutely nothing**. So now I have empirical evidence it is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the boot prefetcher is too load data which are used in later boot phases when the PC hangs at a task during earlier boot stages. This is done, because normal HDDs are slow reading random files from the drive. So loading them before they are really needed speeds up boot.

Using a SSD eliminates this bottleneck of and here Windows doesn't benefit from prefetcher any longer. So [Windows disable the prefetcher/Superfetch on the fly for a SSD](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Disabling-Hibernation-Superfetch-onboard-VGA#time=05m50s) and here running the commands is pointless.